# Конфликт версий com.android.support

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-android

Пару дней назад столкнулся с проблемой - конфликт `com.android.support` библиотек. Где-то в зависимостях засела устаревшая версия `26.1.0`, а в проекте я использовал `27.1.0`. Сами понимаете, не хорошо это. `Android Studio` на это и указывает в своем сообщении.

[image: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification ...]

```
ext {
    supportLibraries = '27.1.0'

    firebaseCore = '15.0.2'
    firebaseAds = '15.0.1'
    firebaseInvites = '15.0.1'

    crashLytics = '2.9.3'
    // ниже версии других зависимостей
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // com.android:SUPPORT:
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraries"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraries"

    // com.google.FIREBASE:
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseCore") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$firebaseAds"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:$firebaseInvites"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$crashLytics"
    // ниже версии других зависимостей
}
```

Гуглил, читал SO, ruSO, толкового, нужного мне, решения так и не нашел. В итоге смог самостоятельно решить вопрос. Чем сейчас и делюсь с `Android` сообществом в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно в такой конфигурации `build.gradle` уровня `app` у меня все собралось без уведомлений и предупреждений.

```
ext {
    supportLibraries = '27.1.1'

    firebaseCore = '16.0.0'
    firebaseAds = '15.0.1'
    firebaseInvites = '16.0.0'

    crashLytics = '2.9.3'
    // ниже идут другие зависимости, не относящиеся к теме вопроса
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // com.android:SUPPORT:
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraries"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraries"

    // com.google.FIREBASE:
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseCore"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:$firebaseInvites"
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$firebaseAds") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$crashLytics"
    // ниже идут другие зависимости, не относящиеся к теме вопроса
```

И, конечно же, полезная ссылочка на сводку последних версий библиотек `Firebase`.
Да, они гуглятся в два счета, но лучше когда все и сразу.

[Доступные версии библиотек Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries)